# Install older version of GLibc on RHEL

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rpm, gcc, glibc

I'm trying to install GCC 4.4 on RHEL6: `sudo rpm -ivh /mnt/dvd/Packages/gcc-4.4.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`. But the problem is that is depends on `glibc` and `glibc-common` libraries. When I try to install them using the command

```
sudo rpm -ivh /mnt/dvd/Packages/glibc-common-2.11.1-1.10.el6.x86_64.rpm /mnt/dvd/Packages/glibc-2.11.1-1.10.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I get following the error:

```
file *.so from install of glibc-2.11.1-1.10.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.7.el6.x86_64
```

How could I make GLibc 2.11 installed instead of 2.12? Is there any other way to install GCC without downgrading to GLibc 2.11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible you're using a RHEL 6-Beta DVD on a RHEL 6.0 system?

It looks like RHEL 6 has always had glibc 2.12 but the beta release had glibc 2.11. I really can't find a definitive source that says what the 6-Beta had but find mentions of 2.11 on 6-Beta around the web like [here](https://ccs-unix.berkeley.edu/public/RHEL6) and [here](http://ftp.riken.go.jp/archives/Linux/redhat/ftp.redhat.com/rhel/beta/6/x86_64/os/Packages/). All of the [CentOS src.rpms](http://vault.centos.org/) for 6.0 to 6.3 are glic 2.12 so the final release has always had 2.12.

Is it possible you initially installed from the 6-beta DVD but have upgraded to a newer RHEL release since then? If so, you really can't use the packages from an older RHEL DVD. If you're just trying to install gcc, you can run `yum install gcc` to get GCC 4.4.x. In general, installing through yum is preferred over the DVD since yum will automatically fetch the latest RPMs whereas the DVD might have an older version that has some bugs. If you really want the DVD method, you'll need to get a DVD that matches the RHEL 6 release you have installed.

`cat /etc/redhat-release` will tell you what version of RHEL you're running. I'm guessing you're on 6.0 since the version of [glibc currently installed is from November 2010](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2010-0872.html) (you should look in to upgrading to 6.3 at some point). As for how to tell what version the DVD is, I'm guessing if you boot from it, it will say RHEL 6 Beta or something on the splash screen. Maybe read the docs on the DVD to see if it references being a beta?

Comment: it seems that you're right. `cat /etc/redhat-release` shows `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)` and iso image filename is `RHEL6.0-20100414.0-AP-x86_64-DVD1.iso`. There are also two files at the root of the dvd: `RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta-2` and `RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release-2`.

`yum install gcc` does not work. It says that `glibc-common = 2.5-81.el5_8.4` and `cpp = 4.1.2-52.el5_8.1` are required.

Comment: @altern From the error you're getting, it looks like your repos are set up for RHEL 5 instead of RHEL 6. Since you're paying for Red Hat support, you could try calling them to help sort out the situation. Otherwise, in a pinch you could use the CentOS 6.0 gcc RPM at http://vault.centos.org/6.0/os/x86_64/Packages/gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64.rpm . You might have to manually resolve dependencies for other RPMs which could be painful.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the source RPM and rebuild it so it uses the system libs you have (2.12).